# Multiprocessing in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have two variables which need to be defined successively. How can I define them with multiprocessing?

```
train_X = preprocess_data(train_X)
test_X = preprocess_data(test_X)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A `Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) makes this easy enough:

```
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    train_X, text_X = pool.map(preprocess_data, (train_X, test_X))
```

Just make sure you're doing enough work to process that it's worth piping the data to and from the child processes (which happens implicitly when you use `Pool` workers).